# Change button color based on screen size

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, viewport

What I am trying to achieve is when my device size is less than 736 px, the button should animate. I got the button working correctly, however, I’m struggling to work with the specific screen size.

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).width() <= 736) {
    // do something
    
    let myBtn = document.querySelector(".btn");
    let btnStatus = false;

    myBtn.style.background = "#FF7F00";

    function bgChange() {
      if (btnStatus == false) {
        myBtn.style.background = "#FF0000";
        btnStatus = true;
      }
      else if (btnStatus == true) {
        myBtn.style.background = "#FF7F00";
        btnStatus = false;
      }
    }

    myBtn.onclick = bgChange;
  }
});
```

```css
.btn {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: .6px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn">CLICK ME</button>
```

Comment: You should solve this with CSS media queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an implementation of what you're trying to do that uses:

1. `class` to alter button styling instead of `style`,
2. vanilla JavaScript instead of jQuery.

Using class is a good idea, as it keeps the styling in the CSS and out of the JavaScript code.

Using vanilla JavaScript whenever you can is preferable.

Here are the two new classes:

```css
.btn-small-screen {
  background: #FF7F00;
}

.btn-clicked {
  background: #FF0000;
}
```

`.btn-small-screen` class is applied when the window is small, `.btn-clicked` is toggled whenever the button is clicked.

Here's the JavaScript code:

```js
let myBtn = document.querySelector('.btn');
let isSmallWindow = () => window.innerWidth <= 736;

function toggleButtonOnClick () {
  myBtn.classList.toggle('btn-clicked');
}

function setButtonMode () {
  if (isSmallWindow()) {
    myBtn.classList.add('btn-small-screen');
    myBtn.addEventListener('click', toggleButtonOnClick);
  } else  {
    myBtn.classList.remove('btn-small-screen');
    myBtn.classList.remove('btn-clicked');
    myBtn.removeEventListener('click', toggleButtonOnClick);
  }
}

// setup mode on resize
window.addEventListener('resize', setButtonMode);

// setup mode at load
window.addEventListener('load', setButtonMode);
```

References:

- [Document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
- [Window.innerWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerWidth)
- [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)
- [DOMTokenList.toggle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle)
- [DOMTokenList.add()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/add)
- [DOMTokenList.remove()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/remove)
- [EventTarget.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

A working example:

```js
let myBtn = document.querySelector('.btn');
let isSmallWindow = () => window.innerWidth <= 736;

function toggleButtonOnClick () {
  myBtn.classList.toggle('btn-clicked');
}

function setButtonMode () {
  if (isSmallWindow()) {
    myBtn.classList.add('btn-small-screen');
    myBtn.addEventListener('click', toggleButtonOnClick);
  } else  {
    myBtn.classList.remove('btn-small-screen');
    myBtn.classList.remove('btn-clicked');
    myBtn.removeEventListener('click', toggleButtonOnClick);
  }
}

// setup small mode on resize
window.addEventListener('resize', setButtonMode);

// setup small mode at load
window.addEventListener('load', setButtonMode);
```

```css
    .btn {
      width: 200px;
      height: 100px;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 40px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 20px;
      letter-spacing: .6px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      border: none;
    }

    .btn-small-screen {
      background: #FF7F00;
    }

    .btn-clicked {
      background: #FF0000;
    }
```

```html
<button class="btn">CLICK ME</button>
```

**Note:** There is one optimization that I left out, so the code would be easier to follow.

Notice that setButtonMode() changes the DOM every time, even though it might already be set to the desired mode. This is inefficient.

To improve efficiency and only change the DOM when necessary, you could introduce a state variable (call it `smallMode`), and set it true whenever appropriate. Like so:

```js
let smallMode = false;

function setButtonMode () {
  if (isSmallWindow()) {
    if (!smallMode) {
      myBtn.classList.add('btn-small-screen');
      myBtn.addEventListener('click', toggleButtonOnClick);
      smallMode = true;
    }
  } else if (smallMode)  {
    myBtn.classList.remove('btn-small-screen');
    myBtn.classList.remove('btn-clicked');
    myBtn.removeEventListener('click', toggleButtonOnClick);
    smallMode = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank You so much, I tested it and working perfectly, it's my bad of finding difficult to understand, however, I believe after some time I will figure out and make myself comfortable with -

Comment: I just added references for all the functions I used, maybe that will help. If anything is unclear, please ask.